APIM and ANOVA mixed?
I am proposing a research project that will include dyadic data in regards to couple satisfaction. It is a randomized controlled trial looking to investigate the efficacy of an intervention on increasing couple satisfaction and treatment adherence of one person. My question is, can I use the APIM model in combination to ANOVA mixed? If yes, then how exactly do I use it? I should mention that I have 2 independent variables, between groups (2 groups) and within different points in time for each participant + 2 dependent variables (couple satisfaction and treatment adherence). Also I have a mediation hypothesis that states couple satisfaction as mediator between intervention and adherence. Thank you!!

I'm not sure about how to combine mixed ANOVA with APIM, but I think you'd find what you're looking for from extensions of APIM. I think what you'd need is a multilevel APIM with a covariate, which I believe is relatively easy to do in both MPlus and R lavaan.

This article may be helpful. Also, I think multilevel models are also commonly used with data like yours (in which case you drop the APIM approach and use MLM instead).
